# Splitting Dictionary on Bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, byte

I have some python code that:

1. Pulls various metrics from different endpoints
2. Joins them in a common dictionary with some standardized key/values
3. Uploads the dictionary to another tool for analysis

While this generally works, there are issues when the dictionary gets too large, it causes performance issues in various points.

I've seen examples using itertools to split based on ranges of keys, to evenly split based on number of keys. However, I would like to try and split it based on the size in bytes, as some of the metrics are drastically larger than others.

Can a dictionary be dynamically split into a list of dictionaries based on the size in bytes?

Comment: How is that dictionary "uploaded"? When you say "too large" do you mean for transmitting the data or processing it on the target machine?

Comment: Can you give a sample? Are the keys strings for example?

Comment: @a_guest - the dictionary is POST'd to an API Gateway which saves it as a file. That file is then ingested by another platform. While the default limit on API Gateways of 10MB is one concern that I could solve in other ways, we've noticed performance issues in the platform on 5-6MB uploads that have been ingested into the analysis platform.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - The key/value pairs vary. The key names are all strings, the values can be ints, strings, or nested dicts/lists of dicts. Its the nested lists of dictionaries that can sometimes grow arbitrarily large.

Comment: @stranjer. I've updated my answer. As long as you have enough items to be able to split at the top level, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both keys and values are sane types that you can call [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) on in a meaningful way, and all distinct objects, you can use that information to split your dictionary into equal-ish chunks.

First compute the total size if you want the max chunk to be a divisor of that. If your maximum size is fixed externally, you can skip this step:

```
total_size = sum(getsizeof(k) + getsizeof(v) for k, v in my_dict.items())
```

Now you can iterate the dictionary, assuming approximately random distribution of sizes throughout, cutting a new dict before you exceed the `max_size` threshold:

```
from sys import getsizeof

def split_dict(d, max_size):
    result = []
    current_size = 0
    current_dict = {}
    while d:
        k, v = d.popitem()
        increment = getsizeof(k) + getsizeof(v)
        if increment + current_size > max_size:
            result.append(current_dict)
            if current_size:
                current_dict = {k: v}
                current_size = increment
            else:
                current_dict[k] = v  # going to list
                current_dict = {}
                current_size = 0
        else:
            current_dict[k] = v
            current_size += increment
    if current_dict:
        result.append(current_dict)
    return result
```

Keep in mind that [`dict.popitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) is descructive: you are actually removing everything from `my_dict` to populate the smaller versions.

Here is a highly simplified example:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> d = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(ascii_letters)}
>>> total_size = sum(getsizeof(k) + getsizeof(v) for k, v in d.items())
>>> split_dict(d, total_size // 5)
[{'Z': 51, 'Y': 50, 'X': 49, 'W': 48, 'V': 47, 'U': 46, 'T': 45, 'S': 44, 'R': 43, 'Q': 42},
 {'P': 41, 'O': 40, 'N': 39, 'M': 38, 'L': 37, 'K': 36, 'J': 35, 'I': 34, 'H': 33, 'G': 32},
 {'F': 31, 'E': 30, 'D': 29, 'C': 28, 'B': 27, 'A': 26, 'z': 25, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'w': 22},
 {'v': 21, 'u': 20, 't': 19, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 'o': 14, 'n': 13, 'm': 12},
 {'l': 11, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'c': 2},
 {'b': 1, 'a': 0}]
```

As you can see, the split is not necessarily optimal in terms of distribution, but it ensures that no chunk is bigger than `max_size`, unless one single entry requires more bytes than that.

**Update For Not-Sane Values**

If you have arbitrarily large nested values, you can still split at the top level, however, you will have to replace `getsizeof(v)` with something more robust. For example:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping, Iterable

def xgetsizeof(x):
    if isinstance(x, Mapping):
        return getsizeof(x) + sum(xgetsizeof(k) + xgetsizeof(v) for k, v in x.items())
    if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isintance(x, str):
        return getsizeof(x) + sum(xgetizeof(e) for e in x)
    return getsizeof(x)
```

Now you can also compute `total_size` with a single call:

```
total_size = xgetsizeof(d)
```

Notice that this is bigger than the value you saw before. The earlier result was

```
xgetsizeof(d) - getsizeof(d)
```

To make the solution really robust, you would need to add instance tracking to avoid circular references and double-counting.

I went ahead and wrote such a function for my library [haggis](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), called [`haggis.objects.getsizeof`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.objects.getsizeof). It behaves largely like `xgetsizeof` above, but much more robustly.